# Angle of Contact with change in temperature or addition of impurities

Tags: surface-tension, fluid-statics

I read that,

> Angle of contact decrease with the addition of impurities whereas it increases if the temperature is increased

For the explanation of why it increases with increase in temperature, I found out that the surface tension causes the increase in cohesive forces and hence a upward concave. So when temperature rises, surface tension decreases and angle of contact increases.

Is this explanation correct, and could you explain it in some other way or elaborate about it?

And I was not able to find why does it decrease with increase in impurities

Source:

[image: From the Book: Self Study Guide for online BITSAT 2017]

*From the Book: Self Study Guide for online BITSAT 2017*

Comment: Is this regarding wetting?Also adding of impurities to the water?Or adding of impurities to the surface?And in which manner...surface dust or incorporating into the surface?Could you please share your source?

Comment: @Chappy My source is a textbook used for an entrance exam preparation. I am not sure about the answer to all of your questions, I can include the image of what is given. It is describing the angle of contact in a capillary tube with different fluids. And it would be impurities added to the fluid, as far as I could comprehend it

Answer (score 2):

Surface tension generally decreases on increasing the temperature i.e adhesion increases. Hence, angle of contact will increase. 
In case of impurities, when a highly soluble impurity like NaCl is added to water, surface tension increases whereas it decreases for sparingly solube (eg: phenol) or insoluble impurities. Hence, angle of contact (on addition of impurities) will decrease or increase accordingly.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The angle of contact can vary with temperature and the nature of impurity added. Consider the simple case of a drop of water on a surface.

***Temperature***

$\rightarrow$ An increase in temperature causes an increase in the kinetic energy of the particles, and an increase in the randomness of their movements, and a decrease in surface tension.

$\rightarrow$ Surface tension is the tension of the surface film caused by the attraction of particles at the surface layer by the bulk.

$\rightarrow$ When the surface tension decreases, it essentially means that the cohesive force would decrease. When the cohesive force is less than the adhesive force (as in, between the water drop and the surface) the angle of contact would decrease.

$\rightarrow$ You can imagine the water drop flattening on the surface as the surface tension decreases, and so you can also visualise the angle of contact decreasing.

***Nature of impurity***

$\rightarrow$ The effect of an impurity on the surface tension and thereby on the angle of contact depends on its solubility within the liquid (in this case, water).

$\rightarrow$ When highly soluble impurities are added to the liquid, it increases cohesive force/surface tension. This would cause an increase in the angle of contact. You could visualise it like how a drop of mercury would behave on glass.

$\rightarrow$ When an impurity with low solubility in the liquid is added, it decreases the cohesive force/surface tension. This would cause a decrease in the angle of contact.

Answer (score -2):

Surface tension increases or decreases depending on the impurity added

- **highly soluble impurity(e.g.=$\rm NaCl$,$\rm ZnSO_4$,Inorganic Salts):**
  When they get added into the liquids, adhesive force between liquid molecule and that impurity molecule increases because of the stronger intermolecular force of attraction, hence surface tension increases.
- **Less Soluble Impurity(e.g. Soap, Sparingly Soluble Salts)**
  When they get added to liquids, adhesive force between liquid molecule and that impurity molecule is less than cohesive force among liquid molecule because weaker intermolecular force of attraction among molecules  causes lower surface tension.

Comment: Use appropriate capitalisation while writing answers. It was not fun to edit this post. We only capitalise the first letter of the first word of each sentence (and proper nouns and some other stuff). Do not use contractions like 'cause' instead of 'because'. It looks sloppy and this isn't an SMS. Use appropriate capitalisation for chemical formulae: $ZnSo_4$ is nonexistant.... it's actually $ZnSO_4$ Observe the preview of the output before posting it: your bullet and paragraph formatting was all wrong